# Functions available when writing a new system call

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, kernel

For a college assignment we have to add a system call to the Linux kernel. I have "Hello, World" done no problem. In terms of adding a more complicated call, I know (or at least think) I can't use C functions like malloc, but I'm wondering can I use syscall() to use other system calls?

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Implement-Sys-Call-Linux-2.6-i386/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kernel has its own specific calls for pretty much everything. You don't have access to system calls or `<sys/xxxx.h>` header files.

For your exmaple, yes, you can't use `malloc()` but you can use `kmalloc()`

In older versions of the kernel (2.4) you could use `syscall()` via: `syscallN()` macros. I'm pretty sure that's been removed.

In general `syscalls()` from the kernel is not a good idea. Really system calls are just a way of user space going into the kernel to do something, so if you're already in the kernel there should be a better way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have a strong suspicion that a syscall from within the kernel is the fast route to a panic!